# How to compile the qt .uic file with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, compilation, qt-creator

How do I link up the C++ files with the .uic files in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.ui` are user interface files generated by designer. They are processed by `uic`. Try `uic -h` for help information.

`qmake` will generate xcode project files by default or can generate Makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use [qmake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake). This tool greatly simplifies the Qt compilation process. 
All .ui files have to be converted into C++ code, and compiled.
All classes that inherit from QObject have to be processed by the meta object compiler.

Comment: Yes it does. It also calls moc for all your QObject classes. Qmake automates the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rule in Xcode.  See this link for the rule adding info for the moc

http://gauthieralexandreblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/qt-and-xcode-4-5-how-to-moc-q_object-classes-automatically/

You will probably want to add rules for both the moc and uic.

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and under the Build Rules tab I selected "Copy To Target" for "System C Rule".  That gives me a little window where I set it up like so:

Process: "Source Files With Names Matching"  *.ui
 Using: "Custom Script"

Script:
/Users/develop-brooke/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/uic -o ${INPUT_FILE_DIR}/GeneratedFiles/ui_${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.h ${INPUT_FILE_PATH}

Output File:
${INPUT_FILE_DIR}/GeneratedFiles/ui_${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.h

Obviously point to your directory of Qt.  You could omit the GeneratedFiles directory if you want.
Add all of your ui files to the Build Phase: Compile Sources.  Once you build it once, go back and make sure the path to these files is in your project.  I added them to my project.

Best,
Brooke